# How to solve this circuit using KCL

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, dc

I understand the super node aspect of this circuit, but I'm unsure of what to do as I dont see a direct way to proceed with KCL using all of the nodes. I found the equation for the supernode, but I'm unsure of the rest.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvMGbo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Supernode: 12=v1-v2
  node 1: 1=v1 + ???
  node 2: ???

Comment: How would you approach this if the 12V supply were replaced with a resistor? Mostly, I just want to know if you can apply KCL/KVL for nodal analysis (assuming that's the approach you wanted to take), at all. Or if your situation is more *remedial*.

Comment: I would do: v1 : 1= (v1 -v2)/R + ???. The thing that I'm unsure about is what the current leaving node 1 to the left would be.

Comment: Well, I don't even bother with supernodes. Some folks are taught to use them. But I think it (1) complicates the situation and makes it look as though one needs to memorize a host of varying situations to make some magic recipe work out -- impairing your ability to think about novel situations; and, (2) it's not necessary and never was. So, why don't you assign a variable for the current in the 12V voltage supply and then perform normal nodal analysis? Have you tried considering that?

Comment: The idea of supernode is that you write KCL for it and not for nodes 1 and 2. You write sum of currents flowing in and out of the supernode in terms of voltages V1 and V2 and combine the equation with V1-V2=12. This works well when the circuit has only one node apart from the supernode. This is the case in your circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly redrawn schematic.

(I'm keeping it mostly as you had it, because nodal analysis isn't about understanding a circuit's design and behavior and more about just applying a systematic mathematical approach. And it's also just an academic exercise -- the schematic isn't supposed to *do* anything, anyway, except pose a problem to solve using a tool.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZlLFY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I intentionally dropped the ground connections on the other side of your current sources. That connection isn't needed as current sources have \$\infty\$ impedance. I also re-labeled your two nodes to avoid confusion with \$V_2\$ in your schematic.

I've also introduced a new variable for the current in \$V_2\$. This is an unknown variable, but it will be resolved if you solve out the equations.

For each node in the schematic above, I'll list the out-flowing currents from that node on the left side of each equation and I'll list the in-flowing currents into that node on the right side of each equation. The last equation provides the final information relating node 1 and node 2, as you already know.

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{r}
  {\text{Node } 1:} \vphantom{\frac{V_{N_2}}{R_3}}
  \\\\
  {\text{Node } 2:} \vphantom{\frac{V_{N_2}}{R_3}}
  \\\\
  {\text{Assign}:} \vphantom{V_{N_2}+V_2}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
      \frac{V_{N_1}}{R_1}+\frac{V_{N_1}}{R_3}
      \\\\
      \frac{V_{N_2}}{R_2}+\frac{V_{N_2}}{R_3}+I_{V_2}
      \\\\
      V_{N_1}
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=} \vphantom{\frac{V_{N_2}}{R_3}}
  \\\\
  &\quad{=} \vphantom{\frac{V_{N_2}}{R_3}}
  \\\\
  &\quad{=} \vphantom{V_{N_2}+V_2}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      \frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{V_{N_2}}{R_3}+I_1+I_{V_2}
      \\\\
      \frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{V_{N_1}}{R_3}+I_2
      \\\\
      V_{N_2}+V_2 
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

Can you solve the above for \$V_{N_1}\$, \$V_{N_2}\$, and \$I_{V_2}\$?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and is really straight forward. Thank you for the in-depth explanation. Is it just a difference in convention between the method you used and what I am acustomed to? Ex Vn1 - Vn2 / R3 + ... = ...

Comment: @Thomas I've never seen my method documented in any book. It is how I interpreted (made a mental model) of undocumented code I saw when reading Spice source code to see how it approached solving circuit problems. The Spice code was NOT written because of this insight, though. It was written that way for different reasons (having to do with how it moves from node to node to node.) But after seeing it work right, I created my own mental analogy to explain it to myself.

Comment: @jonk Although the system of equations is correct, its explanation is not. VN1/R3 is not an outflowing current, for example. (VN1-VN2)/R3 is the outflowing current.

Comment: @AlexVB You misunderstand the approach. What I show here is exactly how SPICE code develops its solutions. I've been attempting to teach it here. It's not found in traditional textbooks. If you want, you can simply verify by rearranging my equations. You'll find them to be equivalent to anything you develop. I find the technique much better because mistakes in sign are far less likely.

Comment: @jonk I perfectly understand your approach. And I said that equations are correct. But what you call outflowing currents are not them and this may confuse people.

Comment: @AlexVB The idea is expressed in different posts, elsewhere, that I've written. The point is to reduce mistakes in sign. And it does that well. Since my time is limited right now, I'll try and point you to those discussions later when I have access to a PC. And yes, I'm very well aware that this approach isn't presented well in textbooks and for those so trained they may struggle. But the change in perspective is worth it. Superposition applies here just the same. I will also refer you to a book where this method is also found when I get a moment. It is not wrong. Nor is it unused.

Comment: @AlexVB I also fully intend to continue teaching it, as I've found students make fewer mistakes in sign given the same time applying the idea. They definitely get it right more often. There's a quote you can find in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/547183/38098) discussing how to "read" such equations. The verbage is no more incorrect than any other. So all we do is debate the meaning of words. Which is pointless. The book I would refer you to is Andrei Vladimirescu's "*The SPICE Book*." The technique is applied there, for example.